# PHP Regex how can i capture just the names?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture just the names without the numbers or whitespace at the start.

For example, My names are like this:

```
0410 - Game Name One (Europe)
0650- Game Name Two(Europe)
5874 -Game Name Three (Europe)
3698  -  Game Name Four (Europe)
```

I can't just remove the first 6 characters because sometimes there is extra spaces or no spaces at all.

I want to end up with just the following:

```
Game Name One (Europe)
Game Name Two(Europe)
Game Name Three (Europe)
Game Name Four (Europe)
```

I tried doing this but it just failed so hoping i can get some help.

```
(\d+)\s-\s(.*?)
```

Comment: try this: \d+\s*-\s*(.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
^\d+\s*-\s*(.+)
```

You'll find the name in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+\s*-\s*
```

Replace by `empty string`.use `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

For your case the following should do:

```
[A-Za-z].*
```

The name portion can start with `g` or `G` or any other uppercase/lowercase letter.

A more general solution would be:

```
(?!.*?-)\w.*
```

Check: https://regex101.com/r/mD3bJ7/1

Comment: @Exoon: You are right but it was just the OP's example specific solution..now i have added a general one..